# How can I get a PDB file for the EntityFramework NuGet package?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, pdb-files

I'm trying to debug a StackOverflow in the EntityFramework NuGet package (version 6.1.3). In order to see the stack frames I need the PDB file for EntityFramework.DLL and EntityFramework.SqlServer.DLL. However, I can't seem to get Visual Studio to download this from either the MSFT symbol sources or from SymbolSource.org (I can get other System PDBs and things like NewtonSoft.json). Are the EF PDBs available anywhere?

Comment: Did one of these answers worked for you?

Answer (score 29):

Now with pictures (as it took me about an hour of trial and fail)

1. Get [DotPeek from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (Standalone version)
2. Open `DotPeek` -> `File` -> `Open` -> browse to your project `bin` folder and open `EntityFramework.dll`
3. <kbd>Right mouse</kbd> button on `EntityFramework` then choose `Generate Pdb...`
   [image]

[image]

4. Go to folder where you exported it and open `EntityFramework.pdb` folder (I know right!) then dig deeper till you find a file `EntityFramework.pdb` and copy it to your `bin` folder (next to `EntityFramework.dll`).
5. Go to `Visual Studio` -> `DEBUG` -> `Options and Settings...` -> `Symbols` then add your `bin` folder to `Symbol file (.pdb) locations`

[image]

6. Run project and pray those breakpoints turn ripe red....

**Edit:** It sometimes starts running EF in `optimized` mode that renders debugging pretty much useless which is a whole point of this question - if this happens

7. Go to `Visual Studio` -> `Debug` -> `General` -> (at the very bottom) `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`. Tick and Run project (if it gets optimized then untick and run, then tick again and run, then ....)

[image]

8. To see if `EF` runs optimized without having to wait till it hits breakpoint Go to `Visual Studio` -> `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Modules`. Then when you run solution modules (2) should appear. Click it and find `EntityFramework.dll` there should be column that says Optimized(`Yes` = bad, `No` = you can debug it).

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Great explaination @Matas! Thx!

Comment: It seems that DotPeek doesn't hook itself to VS2017, but you can do the same process by using the GUI that is installed along.

Comment: For anyone else who is still setting Optimizations on there dll make sure the `Supress JIT Optomization on Module load` is checked

Comment: Do you really need to do step 5 if you already put the `.pdb` in your `bin` directory? I mean, you will have to change it for every project if you hardcode it...

Answer (score 13):

Download the source code:
[entity framework on codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

The download button is in the sub-menu on the Source tab

Once downloaded:

- Build the solution/project
- Navigate to the bin directory **NB**: it is not in the normal location, its set to `"..\..\bin\Debug\"`. See Project properties.

The EntityFramework.pdb and the EntityFramework.SqlServer.pdb are both there.

Also would of thought, it would be available by default or easier.

Comment: I can't believe that this is the only answer to this question

Comment: I'm surprised i didn't get any cred, #justsaying ;-) totally agree tho... had to dig to only get to this...

Comment: up for the exclusive (albeit not satisfying) answer to this question

Comment: One note: I didn't need the pdb file myself. I was hoping to get more info of my Exception. But the info was already there. I just had to inspect the $exception variable in the local variable window of visual studio.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it has to be the exact same version that you are running in your project. And EF hasn't always had a sensible versioning scheme

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is to use [dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) as symbol server (load entity framework dll and add dotpeek serer address copied from dotpeek settings) - what is great about this approach, that it generated pdb matching used dll version automatically, what is not so great - it will not contain original comments from source code, etc.

Comment: This also works without the Symbol Server mode. You can generate a pdb file for an assembly and point Visual Studio to the folder dotPeek creates.